# SET A VALUE TO PIN BY MONITORING SAME PIN IN VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Is it possible to set an inout pin to specific value when after monitoring the value in same pin.ie if we have an inout signal then if value on that signal is one then after doing specific operation can we set value of that pin to zero in vhdl.

Comment: Explain what you want to do and what have you tried?

Comment: i have to implement a shift register and it has a asynchronous signal load which is inout.when its value is one then i have to load data and when its value is zero then we have to shift data .so after loading the data the load signal has to made zero. ie after a '1' occurs in load we have to change the value to 0.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing doesn't make a lot of sense. Are you sure you are understanding the requirements correctly?

Your `load` signal sounds like an external control signal that is an input into your module. You should not be trying to change the value of that signal - whoever is controlling your module should do that instead.

As long as the `load` signal is asserted (`1`), you should probably be loading your shift register with whatever value is presumably being provided on a different input signal (e.g., `parallel_data`). When the `load` signal is deasserted (`0`) by the external logic, you should probably start shifting out one bit of the loaded data per clock cycle to your output signal (e.g., `serial_data`).

Note that there is no need for bidirectional signals!

This is all based on what I would consider typical behavior for a shift register, and may or may not match what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a good plan, and I'm not entirely sure you want to do it, but I guess if you can set things up such that:

- you have a resistor pulling the wire down to ground.
- your outside device drives the wire high
- the FPGA captures the pin going high and then also drives it high
- The outside source goes tristate once it has seen the pin go high
- the FPGA can then set the pin tristate when it wants to flag it has finished (or whatever), and the resistor will pull it low again
- repeat

I imagine one use for this would be for the outside device to trigger some processing and the FPGA to indicate when it has finished, in which case, the FPGA code could be something like:

```
pin_name <= '1' when fpga_is_processing = '1' else 'Z';
start_processing <= '1' when pin_name = '1' and pin_name_last = '0';
pin_name_last <= pin_name when rising_edge(clk);
```

`start processing` will produce a single clock pulse on the rising edge of the `pin_name` signal.  `fpga_is_processing` would be an output from your processing block, which must "come back" before he external device has stopped driving the pin high.

You *may* want to "denoise" the edge-detector on the `pin_name` signal to reduce the chances of external glitches triggering your processing.  There are various ways to achieve that also.